# identifying if there is child menu with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dynamic tree menu in html file. the structure is-

```html
<ul id="cat_menu" class="cat_menu">
  <li><a href="#">iPods</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">iPads</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">iPhones</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">3GS</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">4G</a></li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is a vertical tree menu. menu is okay. But i want to show a small arrow if a nav has subnav. Like the 3rd one. I want to show a arrow in "iPhones" nav. for this i have to identify if the nav has any sub. I was trying with jquery-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("ul#cat_menu li").each(function(){
    if($(this:has(ul))){
        $(this).css('background','red');//I will use code here for arrow.
    }
  })

});
```

But its not working. Any help?? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this;

```
$("ul#cat_menu li").each(function(){
    if($('ul',this).length){
        $(this).css('background','red');//I will use code here for arrow.
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid JS code<sup>†</sup>:

```
$(this:has(ul))
```

It should be:

```
$(this).has('ul')
// or alternatively
$(this).find('ul').length
```

---

†: It seems you wanted to use the [**`:has()`**](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector. Selectors **always** have to be strings. If you already have a reference to an object, e.g. with `this`, then you need to find the corresponding method and call this one on `$(this)`.

Comment: @Rudie: Yes, but it calls `$(this).find('ul').length` anyway (internally).

Comment: I think it's the other way around, because that's how Sizzle works, but okay.

Comment: @Rudie: Not in this case, see here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L159

Comment: Haha kewl okay I'm convinced =) I haven't seen jQuery source since `1.3.2`

Answer (score 0):

Your entire implementation can be replaced with this:

```
// nothing happens if there are no matches, no need for a condition
// or the `.each` since ul#cat_menu li's are implicitly iterated
$("ul#cat_menu li").find('ul > li').css("border", "1px solid red");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r3jfw/